# Rename a bluetooth device?

Tags: bluetooth

Android doesn't seem to offer a way to name (or rename) a paired bluetooth device. For example, if I have two identical Bluetooth headsets, I can't readily tell which is which.

Do you know of any way to rename a paired bluetooth device? Perhaps an application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bluetooth device names come from the device itself, so unless there's a way to do this from your headset, this isn't possible, at least on stock Android. A quick google search revealed a [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=963927) that claimed [CyanogenMod 7](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) can do this (it creates an alias for the device, doesn't change the name itself).